Python Pandas: Join on case-insensitive and stripped key
Left Dataframe MASTER =



Fname
Lname
Amount




John
Smith-Richards



David
O'Brien




Right Dataframe ORDERS =



Fname
Lname
Amount




DAVID
OBRIEN
36


john
smith richards
11



Expected output Dataframe =



Fname
Lname
Amount




John
Smith-Richards
11


David
O'Brien
36



The tables MASTER and ORDERS are LEFT-OUTER joined with KEY = [Fname, Lname]
Both tables have the same columns but the rows are not in the same order. I want the join operation to ignore case and ignore characters like dashes, spaces and apostrophes (e.g. the tables would be joined on the values "johnsmithrichards" and "davidobrien")
(In practice, the actual tables have many more columns and the resulting output table must pull some values from the MASTER table and others from the ORDERS table, which is why I used  mdfcols and odfcols respectively to only include those specific columns.)
My attempt at removing just spaces doesn't work:
key = ["Fname", "Lname"]

mdfkey = (mdf["First Name"].str.lower() + mdf["Last Name"].str.lower()).replace(' ', '')
mdfcols = ["Fname", "Lname"]

odfkey = (odf["First Name"].str.lower() + odf["Last Name"].str.lower()).replace(' ', '')
odfCols = ["Amount"]

outputdf = pd.merge(
    mdf.loc[:, mdfcols],
    odf.loc[:, odfCols],
    how='left', left_on=mdfkey, right_on=odfkey)


Create new key column in both DataFrames where you concatenate Fname and Lname, convert them to lowercase, and remove the unwanted characters. Then, you can use this key column to perform the merge.

Use Series.str.replace for remove non alpha numeric values for both DataFrames, last remove helper column key_0:
key = ["Fname", "Lname"]

mdfkey = (mdf["Fname"] + mdf["Lname"]).str.replace('[^a-zA-Z]', '', regex=True).str.lower()
mdfcols = ["Fname", "Lname"]


odfkey = (odf["Fname"] + odf["Lname"]).str.replace('[^a-zA-Z]', '', regex=True).str.lower()
odfCols = ["Amount"]

outputdf = pd.merge(
    mdf.loc[:, mdfcols],
    odf.loc[:, odfCols],
    how='left', left_on=mdfkey, right_on=odfkey).drop('key_0', axis=1)

print (outputdf)
   Fname           Lname  Amount
0   John  Smith-Richards      11
1  David         O'Brien      36

Solution with helper columns:
merging = ['merge']
key = ["Fname", "Lname"]

mdf['merge'] = ((mdf["Fname"] + mdf["Lname"]).str.replace('[^a-zA-Z]', '', regex=True)
                                             .str.lower())
mdfcols = ["Fname", "Lname"]


odf['merge'] = ((odf["Fname"] + odf["Lname"]).str.replace('[^a-zA-Z]', '', regex=True)
                                             .str.lower())
odfCols = ["Amount"]

outputdf = pd.merge(
    mdf.loc[:, mdfcols + merging],
    odf.loc[:, odfCols + merging],
    how='left', on=merging).drop(merging, axis=1)

print (outputdf)
   Fname           Lname  Amount
0   John  Smith-Richards      11
1  David         O'Brien      36

